# javascript split string to get Date and Hours only

Tags: javascript

I have this date format ,

```
var dateobj = 'Apr 28, 2011 6:01:23 AM';
```

I need Apr 28 6 (That is only date and  hours )

Please tell me

I tried this way

```
var amorpm = dateobj.split(' ').slice(0, 3).join(' '); but i am getting only date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a bit more complex than that:

```
var dateArr = dateobj.split(' ');
var amorpm = [dateArr[0], dateArr[1].replace(',', ''), dateArr[3].split(':')[0]].join(' ');
```

Comment: Thanks blender , how can i add AM also to this ??

Comment: I'd try the first answer. It's more versatile.

Comment: @Pavan, I'd seriously go with the answer below. It's easier to work with later on.

Answer (score 5):

```
var dateobj = new Date('Apr 28, 2011 6:01:23 AM');

var m = dateobj.getMonth(); // 3  (0 = January, 3 = April)
var d = dateobj.getDate();  // 28
var h = dateobj.getHours(); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (tested on my browser's javascript console)

```
var dateobj = 'Apr 28, 2011 6:01:23 AM';
> undefined
lst=dateobj.split()
> ["Apr 28, 2011 6:01:23 AM"]
lst=dateobj.split(' ')
> ["Apr", "28,", "2011", "6:01:23", "AM"]
day=lst.slice(0,3).join(' ')
> "Apr 28, 2011"
hms=lst[3].split(':')
> ["6", "01", "23"]
day+' ' + hms[0]
> "Apr 28, 2011 6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
var d = 'Apr 28, 2011 6:01:23 AM';

var s=d.split(/\W+/);
alert([s[0],s[1],s[3]].join(' ')+s[6])
```

returned value: (String)
Apr 28 6AM